# Understanding Memory Report

Tags: ios, memory-management, xcode5

I have a problem that the memory for my app always grows in Xcode 5, on the other hand I didn't find anything what can cause leaks, over-allocated memory etc.

Of course, I understand that no one automatic debug tool can't 100% detect incorrect staff.

I've made simple peace of code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    for (int i = 1; i < 5000; i ++) {
        NSLog(@"i equeal %d", i);
    }

    return;        
}
```

I've launched the project, pressed button 3 times and I've got:

[image]

As you see - each tapping, memory always grows, but why? I really wonder - what, actually, this diagram for and why it happens?

Profiling through Allocations template didn't show anything extra-ordinary:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top graph will be the same as the "Actual Memory Use" shown in Activity Monitor Instrument.  I am nowhere near an expert (and could very easily be wrong), but my theory is that as long as the OS has memory to spare for your application it will give it for your applications use (when your application asks for it).  The OS will not reclaim that memory immediately because it doesn't know if your app will need it in the near future.  So your total available memory that the OS has given to your app will increase with every allocation (assuming the OS has memory to give).

In one of my apps the Allocated memory at any given time is roughly 110 megs, but the Actual Memory Use given by Activity Monitor is in the 160's of megs.  Don't worry too much about the activity monitor.  The memory will be released by the OS when you get a Memory Warning (assuming you are not actually using the memory and not making the app crash).